# a simple single layer perceptron implementation for binary classification with sigmoid activation function

Tags: python, binary, classification, perceptron

Hello i m trying to complete an assignment based on training a perceptron (without any hidden layer) to perform binary classification using sigmoid activation function. but due to some reason my code is not working correctly. although the error is decreasing after each epoch but accuracy is not increasing. i have target labels 1 and 0, but my predicted labels are almost all close to one. none of my predicted label is representing the 0 class.
below is my code. anyone please tell me what have i done wrong.

```
 <# Create a Neural_Network class
class Neural_Network(object):    
    def __init__(self,inputSize = 2,outputSize = 1 ):        
        # size of layers
        self.inputSize = inputSize
        self.outputSize = outputSize    
        #weights
        self.W1 = 0.01*np.random.randn(inputSize+1, outputSize) # randomly initialize W1 using random function of numpy
        # size of the wieght will be (inputSize +1, outputSize) that +1 is for bias    

    def feedforward(self, X): #forward propagation through our network
        n,m=X.shape
        Xbias = np.ones((n,1))    #bias term in input
        Xnew = np.hstack((Xbias,X))   #adding biasterm in input to match the dimension with the weigth
        self.product=np.dot(Xnew,self.W1) # dot product of X (input) and set of weights
        output=self.sigmoid(self.product) # apply activation function (i.e. sigmoid)
        return output # return your answer with as a final output of the network

    def sigmoid(self, s):# apply sigmoid function on s and return its value
        return (1./(1. + np.exp(-s)))     #activation sigmoid function

    def sigmoid_derivative(self, s):#derivative of sigmoid
        #derivative of sigmoid = sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x)) 
        return s*(1-s) # here s will be sigmoid(x) 


    def backwardpropagate(self,X, Y, y_pred, lr):
        # backward propagate through the network

        # compute error in output which is loss, compute cross entropy loss function
        self.output_error=self.crossentropy(Y,y_pred)   #output error

        # applying derivative of sigmoid to the error
        self.error_deriv=self.output_error*self.sigmoid_derivative(y_pred)
        # adjust set of weights
        n,m=X.shape
        Xbias = np.ones((n,1))    #bias term in input
        Xnew = np.hstack((Xbias,X))   #adding biasterm in input to match the dimension with the weigth
        self.W1 += lr*(Xnew.T.dot(self.error_deriv))   # W1=W1+ learningrate*errorderiv*input
        #self.W1 += X.T.dot(self.z2_delta)

    def crossentropy(self, Y, Y_pred):
        # compute error based on crossentropy loss 
        #Cross entropy= sum(Y_actual*log(y_predicted))/N. here 1e-6 is used to avoid log 0
        N = Y_pred.shape[0]
        #cr_entropy=-np.sum(((Y*np.log(Y_pred+1e-6))+((1-Y)*np.log(1-Y_pred+1e-6))))/N
        cr_entropy=-np.sum(Y*np.log(Y_pred+1e-6))/N 
        return cr_entropy #error

    Null=None
    def train(self, trainX, trainY,epochs = 100, learningRate = 0.001, plot_err = True ,validationX = Null, validationY = Null):
        tr_error=[]
        for i in range(epochs):
            # feed forward trainX and trainY and recievce predicted value
            y_predicted=self.feedforward(trainX)
            print(i,y_predicted)
            # backpropagation with trainX, trainY, predicted value and learning rate.
            self.backwardpropagate(trainX,trainY,y_predicted,learningRate)
            tr_error.append(self.output_error)
            print(i,self.output_error)
            print(i,self.W1)
            # """"""if validationX and validationY are not null than show validation accuracy and error of the model.""""""

        # plot error of the model if plot_err is true
        epocharray=range(0,epochs)
        plt.plot(epocharray,tr_error,'r',linewidth=3.0)    #plotting error vs. no. of epochs
        plt.xlabel('No. of Epochs')
        plt.ylabel('Cross Entropy Error')
        plt.title('Error Vs. Epoch')

    def predict(self, testX):
        # predict the value of testX
        self.ytest_pred=self.feedforward(testX)

    def accuracy(self, testX, testY):
        import math
        # predict the value of trainX
        self.ytest_pred1=self.feedforward(testX)
        acc=0
        # compare it with testY
        for j in range(len(testY)):
            q=math.ceil(self.ytest_pred1[j])  
            #p=round(q)
            if testY[j] == q:
                acc +=1
        accuracy=acc/float(len(testX))*100
        print("Percentage Accuracy is", accuracy,"%")
        # compute accuracy, print it and """"""show in the form of picture""""""
        return accuracy # return accuracy> 




    # generating dataset point
np.random.seed(1)
no_of_samples = 2000
dims = 2
#Generating random points of values between 0 to 1
class1=np.random.rand(no_of_samples,dims)
#To add separability we will add a bias of 1.1
class2=np.random.rand(no_of_samples,dims)+1.1
class_1_label=np.array([1 for n in range(no_of_samples)])
class_2_label=np.array([0 for n in range(no_of_samples)])
#Lets visualize the dataset
plt.scatter(class1[:,0],class1[:,1], marker='^', label="class 1")
plt.scatter(class2[:,0],class2[:,1], marker='o', label="class 2")
plt.xlabel('Dimension 1')
plt.ylabel('Dimension 2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Data concatenation
data = np.concatenate((class1,class2),axis=0)
label = np.concatenate((class_1_label,class_2_label),axis=0)
#Note: shuffle this dataset before dividing it into three parts
data,label=shuffle(data,label)
#print(data)

# now using train_test_split command to split data into 60% training data, 20% testing data and 20% validation data
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(data, label, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)  
trainX, validX, trainY, validY = train_test_split(trainX, trainY, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
    model = Neural_Network(2,1)
    # try different combinations of epochs and learning rate
    model.train(trainX, trainY, epochs = 100, learningRate = 0.000001, validationX = validX, validationY = validY)
    model.accuracy( testX,testY)
```

the Results are coming like this(no label going near 0)

```
0 [[0.49670809]
 [0.4958389 ]
 [0.4966064 ]
 ...
 [0.49537492]
 [0.49566927]
 [0.4961255 ]]
0 828.1069658303942
0 [[0.48311074]
 [0.51907406]
 [0.52764299]]
1 [[0.69813116]
 [0.91746189]
 [0.80408611]
 ...
 [0.74821077]
 [0.87150079]
 [0.75187736]]
1 250.96538025031356
1 [[0.56983781]
 [0.59205773]
 [0.60057486]]
2 [[0.72602796]
 [0.94067579]
 [0.83591236]
 ...
 [0.77916283]
 [0.90032058]
 [0.78291184]]
2 210.645081151866
2 [[0.63353102]
 [0.64265939]
 [0.65118627]]
3 [[0.74507968]
 [0.95318096]
 [0.85588864]
 ...
 [0.79953834]
 [0.91705918]
 [0.80329027]]
3 186.2933734713245
3 [[0.6846678 ]
 [0.68164316]
 [0.69020355]]
4 [[0.75952936]
 [0.96114086]
 [0.87010085]
 ...
 [0.81456476]
 [0.92830628]
 [0.81829009]]
4 169.32091332021724
4 [[0.72771826]
 [0.71342293]
 [0.72202744]]
5 [[0.77112943]
 [0.96669774]
 [0.88093323]
 ...
 [0.82635507]
 [0.93649788]
 [0.83004119]]
5 156.53923256347372
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Your code is not runnable at `model.train` because `trainX` is not defined at that location.

Comment: @lincr yes i forgot to add that part, i have added it now. please have a look into it.

Comment: You are missing the derivative term of loss to `y_pred` in your backpropgation function. Besides, genally `cross-entropy` function is used with `softmax` as the last output layer. If `cross-entroy` is not strong needed, you can try something like `mse`.  I modified your code to use `mse` loss, with epochs=1000, lr=1e-4, I got an accuray rate 0f 98%.

Comment: @lincr thanku so much i am also going for mse now and its working

Answer (score 0):

I see you have set learning rate too small. Set it to 0.001 and Increase epoch to 20k and you will see your model learning well.

Plotting error vs epoch's should give you better idea where to stop.

Comment: my model is still not working correctly... any more suggestions?